# how to host web application on android os

Tags: android, linux, tablet-pc, windows-embedded

We started to develop a new project. It will be `a smart home project`. 
Basicly, there will be a tablet sticked on the wall at home. This tablet will do much of the work like communication with the devices, hosting web pages and web services, etc. At this point we don't know which tablet device we should choose for this kind of application. 
The options are:

```
 1. Android tablet (android os)
 2. Linux tablet (a linux os version)
 3. Windows tablet (a windows embedded os version)
```

And this tablet needs to do:

```
 1. Hosting dinamic web pages (like jsp or php web application hosting)
 2. Hosting a simple web service
 3. Showing full screen application (only our application will be shown on the device)
 4. Executing some background tasks related to usb or rs232.
```

We don't know which tablet device and development enverionment we should choose. 
For instance; if we choose android tablet device, in this case we have to find out whether android os supports what we need.
Which operating system and tablet device should we choose according to what we need listed above?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say much about other platforms, but doing it on Android tablet won't require usage of any other language since you can use existing java libraries to handle incoming connections and perform inner logic. And it won't take much time to make fullscreen application.

Comment: so you say android os can host jsp or php web applications? and also web services?

Comment: Well. It is doable. I run once php on my phone. But you should consider pure Android(java) code. Using non-native code may lead to further problems when you'll try to access rs232 or any other hardware.